# VW Wiring Harness Repair / Replacement

Tags: electrical, vw, wiring, tdi

I've got an '02 Jetta TDI (diesel) with ongoing problems (DTCs and low fuel economy) that seem related to the engine electrical system. The codes are all intermittent shorts to ground on various controls – the fuel shutoff solenoid, EGR control, and boost (turbo vane) control.

I'm starting to think that the problems might be in the wiring harness and I'm wondering what my options might be. For example:

- Are harnesses available from the dealer or in the aftermarket?
- Are harness parts available - especially the connectors and terminators?
- Are used harnesses viable options?

I wouldn't mind building my own if the components are available. Would be happy to hear about others experiences and suggestions for how to go about this.

Comment: any codes/problems with the maf or the cold start injector?

Comment: @Ben - We haven't had any MAF codes recently but did have EGR codes that made us question and replace the MAF sensor. I don't the the Mk4 has a cold start injector.

Comment: If you don't have the cold start injector this diagram may be wrong but maybe backtrace the harness from the maf sensor it looks like there is a couple splices that power a bunch of related items.

Comment: @Ben, was there supposed to be a link to a diagram?

Comment: try this link https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55044707/1.9%20early-late.pdf

Comment: @Ben, thanks for that! Found the cold start injector, it's part of the injection pump. Now I just need to figure out what it does...

Comment: @Ben, very helpful wiring diagrams. The layout is different from the VW layout and more readable. Thanks. Any problem with including parts of them in a question? Also, looks like the part they call the "cold start injector" is actually the advance control on the injection pump.

Comment: Go for it I don't mind.